# Pagination Not Working with StandardSetController

Tags: pagination, standardsetcontroller

I have a Query-based search that looks at the selected option as the String for the Query search.  The Query works normally and can see the selected option. I'm able to see the first page of products that are also set to the pagesize of 10, but none of the pagination buttons work. I've tried so many options, but just can't get things to work.  Reviewing Dev Console, I can see the page block and page table are refreshing but data isn't updating. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My Code Snippet

```
public without sharing class SearchVFPController {

public List<Product2> products;
public Integer noOfRecords {get;set;}
public Integer size {get;set;}


public SearchVFPController(){
  products = new List<Product2>();
  size = 10;
}

  public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        //if(setCon == null) {
          if(codeSearchOptions == 'PREFIX'){
            string searchstring = inputValue+'%';
            products = [SELECT id, ProductCode, Name FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode LIKE :searchstring ORDER BY ProductCode ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 9999];
            system.debug(products.size());
              }
              else if(codeSearchOptions == 'SUFFIX'){
              string searchstring = '%'+inputValue;
              products = [SELECT id, ProductCode, Name FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode LIKE :searchstring ORDER BY ProductCode ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 9999];
              }
                else if(codeSearchOptions == 'ANY'){
                  string searchstring = '%'+inputValue+'%';
                  products = [SELECT id, ProductCode, Name FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode LIKE :searchstring ORDER BY ProductCode ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 9999];
                  }
                  else {
                    string searchstring = '%'+inputValue+'%';
                    products = [SELECT id, ProductCode, Name FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode LIKE :searchstring ORDER BY ProductCode ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 9999];
                    }
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(products);
            setCon.setPageSize(size);
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();

        //}
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('PREFIX','PREFIX')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('SUFFIX','SUFFIX'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('ANY','ANY')); 
    return options; 
}

public String getcodeSearchOptions() {
  return codeSearchOptions;
}
              
public void setcodeSearchOptions(String codeSearchOptions) { 
  this.codeSearchOptions = codeSearchOptions; }


public PageReference search_now(){
  showResults = true;
      return null;
}


// Initialize setCon and return a list of records
public List<Product2> getProducts() {
  return (List<Product2>) setCon.getRecords();
}

public Boolean hasNext {
  get {
      getProducts();
      return setCon.getHasNext();
  }
  set;
}


public Boolean hasPrevious {
  get {
      return setCon.getHasPrevious();
  }
  set;
}


public Integer pageNumber {
  get {
      return setCon.getPageNumber();
  }
  set;
}


public void first() {
  setCon.first();
}


public void last() {
  setCon.last();
}


public void previous() {
  setCon.previous();
}


public void next() {
  setCon.next();
}

  
}
```

My VFP snippet

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Search for Any Portion of the Product Code Here" >

            <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" value="{!codeSearchOptions}"> 
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><br/>

            <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" html-class="input_field" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search_now}"/></apex:inputText>  
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="QueryResults"/> 


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb" title = "Products">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Products}" id="pt" var="p" rendered="{!showResults == true}">
            <apex:column value="{!p.ProductCode}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Product Link">
                    <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!p.id}">
                    <apex:outputText value="link to Product">
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" reRender="pt,pb" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" reRender="pt,pb" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!setCon.next}" rendered="{!hasNext}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" reRender="pt,pb" />
        <apex:commandButton value="End" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" reRender="pt,pb" />
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Since `pt` is inside `pb`, you should be able to just `reRender="pb"`, rather then specify both. That may be causing problems.

Comment: @sfdcfox No go on the reRender="pb".  I'm still only seeing the first 10 records.

Comment: Had a friend assist.  The resolution was to clean-up the code by removing all the individual methods at the bottom and uncomment the "if(setCon == null)" at the top.  Everything is working now.